# Is it possible to connect to RDS DB with IAM User Authentication enabled using pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, pgadmin

I recently setup users on my RDS PostgreSQL DB to authenticate with their IAM User credentials using generated and short lived Tokens, along the lines of this article: [Allow users to connect to RDS with IAM credentials](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/). Everything works like a charm from the command line. However some users would like to access the DB with tools such as pgAdmin.

Is there a way to enable pgAdmin to generate these tokens when necessary?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware you cannot use PGAdmin to generate these tokens. That doesn't mean you cannot use pgadmin to connect to your database with IAM authentication.

You can upload the AWS database root certificate to PGAdmin local storage, and have your database users generate db tokens when they want to connect to the database.

These tokens can be copy pasted into pg-admin's password field when connecting to a server. (Note: The tokens will be far longer than regular passwords typically are)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I thought of just copy pasting the tokens, but that might potentially need to happen several times a day which makes it very cumbersome.

Comment: That's true. I think the best you're going to do is create an alias for `aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <yourhost> --port <yourport> --username <yourusername> --region us-east-1 --profile <your-profile> | pbcopy` and have it automatically select and copy to your clipboard. This is my current personal workflow.